# How to write dictionary to csv file that already exists and already contains headers?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm still kind of new to python, so please excuse my ignorance. I have a CSV file, and it already containers the headers in the first row: `column_1`,`column_2`, and `column_3`. I have a dictionary that maps the columns' names to their respective integers, and I would like to write this dictionary in the CSV file, with the integers appearing in the next row. However, `1` keeps getting appended at the end of `column_3`, as in `column_31`, and `2` and `3` appear in the two cells right next to `column_3`.

```
bigdict = {'column_1':1,'column_2':2,'column_3':3}

f = path

with open(f,'a+') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['column_1','column_2','column_3']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames,delimiter=',')
    csv_file.readline()
    writer.writerow(bigdict)
```

I have written text files before, I have read CSV files, and I have also 'opened' non-existing CSV files and written dictionaries to them, but writing dictionaries to existing CSV files is trumping me for some reason.

Above, I did not create the headers, because they already existed. I wrote `csv_file.readline()` so that the script can read the second row, instead of later writing the dictionary to the first row. When I finally call `.writerow`, for some reason, it's writing the dictionary values appended to the end of the first row, as described above...

What am I doing wrong here?

I followed Rakesh's method below, and I got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-30-a0a3cb0b4ddd>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/[name]/Documents/webscraper/tests/dictwritetoexistingcsv.py', wdir='/Users/[name]/Documents/webscraper/tests')

  File "/Users/[name]/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/[name]/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/[name]/Documents/webscraper/tests/dictwritetoexistingcsv.py", line 13, in <module>
writer.writerow(bigdict)

  File "/Users/[name]/anaconda/lib/python3.6/csv.py", line 155, in writerow
return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: What version of python are you using, if its 3.x file mode 'a+', should work fine for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping I understood your question correctly, I think the problem is that your csv file does not have the newline character at the end of the last row. So, I'll check for that first before going ahead and appending the new row.

I'm starting with this simple csv file named `bigcsv.csv` which is in the same directory with the script. It's contents initially are:

```
column_1,column_2,column_3
a, b, c
```

This is the code:

```
import os
import csv

dir_path = os.getcwd()
file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, "bigcsv.csv")


bigdict = {'column_1': 1, 'column_2': 2, 'column_3': 3}

with open(file_path, 'a+') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',')
    if '\n' not in csv_file.readlines()[-1]:
        csv_file.write("\n")
    writer.writerow(bigdict)
```

This is the file after I run the script.

```
column_1,column_2,column_3
a, b, c
1,2,3
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm running python 3.6.0. I ran the exact same code you have, and I got `IndexError: list index out of range`. So, I rewrote the code and assigned `a = csv_file.readlines()` or `a = csv_file.readline()` to see what its contents are. When I printed `a`, it printed nothing (`''`). I definitely saved the CSV file correctly, as `.csv`... I'm running out of things to try.

Comment: OK, I figured out what works. I replaced 'a+' with 'r+', and it works. However I'm not entirely sure why. r+ reads from the beginning of the file, and not from the end, like a+. However, consecutive runs of this script keep correctly outputting the bigdict in the next line, instead of re-replacing the first line. I don't think I quite understand how a+ and r+ work.

Comment: There are different modes for opening a file. I used Python 3.4 in the response above. However, there's a slight difference when it comes to Python 3.6. So, in the 3.6 version, [`'r+'` opens the file for both reading and writing while `'a+'` only opens it in append mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), which essentially writes to the file starting from the last character. So `csv_file.readlines()[-1]` fails with the `IndexError`.

Comment: Consecutive runs of the script correctly output to `bigdict.csv` because `writer.writerow(bigdict)` automatically appends the newline character at the end of the row.